# Get a price of selected item from it's table in select dropdown and show it in input field

Tags: php

I have a table called participation each type of participation has a price and I fetch the participation type from the database as select options... I need when I choose any type from the select option the price of the selected type shown in an input field named total
here is my code

```
<div id="drop1" class="form-group  col-md-6 <?php echo (!empty($participation_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <?php
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $databaseName = "gym";
    $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
    $connect->set_charset("UTF8");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM participation";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    $participation = "";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $participation = $participation."<option>$row[1]</option>";
    }
    ?>
    <select id="participation" name="participation" class="col-md-6 input drop create form-control" >
        <?php
        echo"<option class='create' hidden>Participation Duration</option>"; echo $participation;?>
    </select>
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $participation_err;?></span>
</div>
<br>

<div class="form-group col-md-6 <?php echo (!empty($total_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <label for="price"></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Total Fees" id="total" name="total" class="form-control create total" value="<?php echo $total; ?>">
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $total_err;?></span>
</div>
```

Comment: What fields are available in the table `participation`?  Your question sounds like an AJAX question, but perhaps the info is already available without getting that deep.  Please show the table structure of `participation` and make sure you show where `price` is stored.

Comment: Participation table contains 3 fields ( participation name - price - duration)
I want to pring the price of the participation i select then save them in the customer table so every customer has his participation and total fees to pay and the duration